# How to skip excel sheet duplicate records when importing to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3 and when I uploaded data to my database, it didn't skip the duplicates.

May someone please help me to address this problem?

The code below is used to upload excel files. I'd like to skip duplicate records when a user uploads a previously uploaded excel again.

```php
public function uploadData()
    {
        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
            $path = 'uploads/';
            require_once APPPATH . "/third_party/PHPExcel.php";
            $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|xls';
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('uploadFile')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            }
            if (empty($error)) {
                if (!empty($data['upload_data']['file_name'])) {
                    $import_xls_file = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                } else {
                    $import_xls_file = 0;
                }
                $inputFileName = $path . $import_xls_file;

                try {
                    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
                    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
                    $flag = true;
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($allDataInSheet as $value) {
                        if ($flag) {
                            $flag = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                        $inserdata[$i]['SR_NO'] = $value['A'];
                        $inserdata[$i]['NTN'] = $value['B'];
                        $inserdata[$i]['NAME'] = $value['C'];
                        $inserdata[$i]['BUSINESS_NAME'] = $value['D'];

                        $i++;
                    }
                    $result = $this->import_model->importdata($inserdata);
                    if ($result) {
                        echo "Imported successfully";
                    } else {
                        echo "ERROR !";
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME)
                        . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                echo $error['error'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'd like to skip duplicate records when a user uploads a previously uploaded excel again" - where's the code to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use array_unique() function to the variable which is storing all the data records in array format. This function returns all the unique elements and this way your duplicate data records can be removed..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check every record form database first on the basis on primary or any combination of unique record, if it exist in db then update or skip that record else insert a new record.